# Resolve typing conflicts with Node dependent libraries in Webpack + Typescript

Tags: node.js, webpack, typescript2.0

I'm building an web app that relies on [PDFKit](http://pdfkit.org/). PDFKit can run in the browser using Webpack. Since I'm using Typescript with Webpack I'm including the [@types/node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/node) definitions so that my interfaces with PDFKit work properly.

That causes other parts of the app which utilize browser globals (e.g. Timer) or Webpack runtime globals (e.g. require) where the typings aren't identical to Node to throw errors.

**Does anyone have ideas for a clean way to isolate the Node typing to the files where they are necessary?** In the past I've scattered `any`as necessary - for example:

```
(require as any).ensure(...); // require has no method 'ensure' in Node
let tmr: number = setTimeout(...) as any; // returns a 'Timer' in Node
```

That's just ugly and unsustainable. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround you could disable `require` typing from node.

Set `typeRoots` explicitly in your `tsconfig.json`. In this case `@types` folder won't be used for finding types anymore. In your custom type root you can create index.d.ts file with ///references to typyngs from @types (except node.d.ts). Also you can provide modified custom version of node.d.ts in your custom typing root.

Not a best solution. Cons are obvious: you have to somehow maintain references, and custom version of node typing :)

(For info about typeRoots see http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html)

Update:

One more answer found here:
https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/11324#issuecomment-265046822

You can create separate tsconfig.json files for each group of files, that uses node and that doesn't. There you can explicitly select typings that you want to apply in the group.
You still has to maintain set of typing names, but it is much smaller.